# How to identify current transport, authentication, channel and message encryption type for a WinRM deployment?

Tags: linux, windows, ansible, kerberos, winrm

I'm having a hard time to figure out what mechanisms are used in an existing WinRM deployment.

WinRM is configured through a Group Policy objet within a Windows domain and applies to a set of Windows endpoints. It is used either from Linux with Python library "pywinrm" or Windows with Powershell remoting.

GPO allows automatic configuration of WinRM listeners on Windows hosts. Documentation states that WinRM defaut initial authentication mechanism is Kerberos, which is fine on a domain environment and generating ticket is straighforward.

Strangely, even if an HTTP and an HTTPs listener are configured on each Windows endpoints, issuing a tcpdump on the Linux client (where Ansible resides) shows no traffic for tcp 5985 (destination port for WinRM "HTTP" listener"), instead traffic is directed to SSL WinRM port (tcp 5986) when an Ansible command is issued against a Windows host (see below).

**Ansible**

```
# Ansible command issued from Ansible client machine (Linux)
ansible -m win_ping --vault-id vault@prompt host.domain.tld

host.tld | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}

# Ansible configuration for Windows hosts group on Ansible client machine (Linux)
  ansible_connection: winrm
  ansible_winrm_scheme: https
  ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
  ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
  ansible_winrm_operation_timeout_sec: 60
  ansible_winrm_read_timeout_sec: 70

  ansible_user: user@DOMAIN.TLD
  ansible_password: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  ansible_port: 5986
```

**Network capture**

```
# Traffic detected here on Ansible client machine (Linux) 
tcpdump -vv -i ensXXX dst 10.10.10.10 and dst port 5986

# No traffic visible here on Ansible client machine (Linux) 
tcpdump -vv -i ensXXX dst 10.10.10.10 and dst port 5985
```

On the WinRM side, configuration is as follows:

**WinRM service configuration**

```
# Global service configuration (Windows endpoint)
winrm get winrm/config/Service

Service
    RootSDDL = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false [Source="GPO"]
    Auth
        Basic = true [Source="GPO"]
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = true [Source="GPO"]
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    IPv6Filter [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
```

**WinRM listener**

```
# winrm listener configuration (Windows endpoint)
winrm enumerate winrm/config/listener

Listener [Source="GPO"]
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTP
    Port = 5985
    Hostname
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10

Listener
    Address = *
    Transport = HTTPS
    Port = 5986
    Hostname = HOST.TLD
    Enabled = true
    URLPrefix = wsman
    CertificateThumbprint = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    ListeningOn = 127.0.0.1, 10.10.10.10
```

On the other hand I have a Web application based on Django which rely on pywinrm to make queries against Windows hosts from a Linux server and this time it seems that WinRM traffic is directed to non SSL TCP port 5985 on Windows endpoint:

**Django application**

```
# Code extract 
winrm_session = winrm.Session(self.server, auth=(self.principal, self.password), transport=self.transport, server_cert_validation='ignore')
command = "gci"
run_ps = winrm_session.run_ps(command)
winrm_output = run_ps.std_out.decode('unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
winrm_output_json = json.loads(winrm_output)
```

**Network capture**

```
# No traffic visible here on Django client machine (Linux) 
tcpdump -vv -i ensXXX dst 10.10.10.11 and dst port 5986

# Traffic visible here on Django client machine (Linux) 
tcpdump -vv -i ensXXX dst 10.10.10.11 and dst port 5985
```

Why is WinRM traffic directed to the either TCP port 5986 (SSL) or TCP port 5985 even if Kerberos is used as for the initial authentication and later for message transport? How to figure out what authentication, transport, etc... are used for a specific WinRM query?

I spotted the difference between WinRM traffic from Ansible and WinRM traffic from Django/pywinrm during troubleshooting of a firewall rule which seemed to prevent WinRM queries depending wether it originated from Ansible or Django/pywinrm.